# Spitter Unsatisfied Dependency Exception Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, action

I starting in Spring MVC with the Book Spring in Action, I'm making the exercise of the chapter 5, with the Spitter application but I got the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spittleController' defined in file [C:\xampp\htdocs.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\spitter\WEB-INF\classes\com\spitter\web\SpittleController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.spitter.data.SpittleRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.spitter.data.SpittleRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spitter.data.SpittleRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I got the project here in github: https://github.com/kevingcfcb88/spitter.git

I already do my research but nothing seems to work.

I'm using STS and Maven, this is the structure of the app:

[image: Project Structure]

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.spitter.config</groupId>
<artifactId>spitter</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spitter</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>          
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>spitter</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>spitter</finalName>
</build>
```

And my config files:

SpittrWebAppInitializer.java

```
 package com.spitter.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
package com.spitter.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.spitter.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

RootConfig.java

```
package com.spitter.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.spitter.data" }, excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfig {

}
```

Comment: SplitterRepository is an interface and not spring component. So there is nothing. Maybe this should be a spring-data-jpa thing?

Comment: Exactly is an interface, but is the way is done in the book.

Comment: Three options: 1. Book is incorrect; 2. Your interpretation of the book is incorrect; 3. The code is not supposed to be executed at this stage

Comment: @mh-dev you are right. It should be a jpa thing but this code is missing some other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this code. It used to give me serious headache 2 years ago. 
The eror is in the code OR the book itslef.

Go to the publishers site and download the updated sourcecode. [here](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/9/ef4e0ef-b7bd-4ab8-857d-eb635d18d425/SpringiA4_SourceCode.zip)

or

https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition

Comment: This solve my problem,thanks; but why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I think it's because the spitterrepository interface should be extend the Spring Jparepository. If it doesnt , Spring will reject it because it's not considering it as Bean. sorry for my english.

Comment: The interface in the example is exactly the same that I have, and neither of both extends from any class

Comment: Then its the opposite. SpitterRepository is being implemented by JdbcSpitterRepository just like @Adam Rosini (see answer below) demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

As @mh-dev explained, you need an implementation of `SpittleRepository`. Try adding this class and see if your code can run:

```
public class SpittleRepositoryImpl implements SpittleRepository {

  List <Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count) {
    System.out.println("I need a real implementation! " 
      + "I received max as " + max + " and count as " + count + ".");
  }

}
```

I would suggest re-reading the relevant sections of the book to make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: Nothing, this not solve my problem, but thanks. I already check like 10 times the whole chapter and I didn't find nothing about an implmentation of that interface.

Comment: You were right. The book miss its implementations, I use the same method as the test to its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a repository implementation of SpittleRepository with @Repository in the header, because even though you have added implementation classes, spring IOC is unaware of actual dependency and the example in the book should have worked if you had put all the java files in the same package hierarchy with repository implementation.

```
@Repository
public class SpittleRepositoryDAO implements SpittleRepository {

    public SpittleRepositoryDAO() {

    }

    @Override
    public List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count) {
        List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<Spittle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            spittles.add(new Spittle("Spittle " + i, new Date()));
        }
        return spittles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the implementation of the repository:

```
package com.spitter.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.spitter.data.SpittleRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spittles")
public class SpittleController {

    private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpittleController(SpittleRepository spittleRepository) {
        this.spittleRepository = spittleRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String spittles(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("spittleList", spittleRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20));
        return "spittles";
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

yep, the problem is that you need an implementation of **SpittleRepository**. Cause you can't have an interface as bean, you know. The scan component need at least one implementation of it and with the annotation @Component. That's it ;)